# Venue listing app with role based managers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am creating a venue listing app, for which i need to assign certain users as managers for certain venues, under the role 'venue_manager'. Where a manager should only have access to venues that are assigned to him/her.

I cant really figure out the ideal way to do this. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to split your app on 2 parts here :

> assign certain users as managers for certain venues, under the role
>   'venue_manager'.

You can do it with has_and_belongs_to_many association, for users/venues where venues can have many managers and user can be manager to many venues. You can also simplify it using roles, so whenever you assign some manager to some venue just add new kind of role to the `roles` list ! Roles could be something like: `["venue_A_role", "venue_B_role", "venue_C_role"], generated like "venue_#{venue.name}_role"`

> manager should only have access to venues that are assigned to him/her

You can check this in controller action, probably `show`, if current user actually has access to particular venue (using role or relationships).
If you use roles like above, you can just check like this:

`venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
if current_user.roles.includes? venue.role_name
........
end`

where `#role_name` is just a method in `Venue` class responsible for generating name as for roles !

I'd suggest to use some authorization library like Pundit or CanCan where your auth logic would be isolated from controller.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: okay this is also a good approach, currently what I've done is, 
I have a `has_many :managed_venue, -> {Venue.all}, class_name: 'Venue'`
association that i have used in my user.rb class
I assign the venues to the user then when i need to access I simply 

`@venues = current_user.managed_venues`

Comment: Ok, so last thing is to make authorization logic where user can access only to his venues ! you can do it in VenuesController#show with checking current_user.managed_venues contains that particular venue and then do some appropriate action !

Comment: yep, I have a helper method in the api controller, where it checks the user's role type and if the venue exists in current_user.managed venues.
Works great now!
Thanks!  :D

Answer (score 0):

In your users table you can add boolean columns for whatever roles you want to associate with. You can initialize them to default to zero and write methods in your Users controller to toggle them: `@user.toggle!('venue_manager')`. Finally, you can check in your views or controllers whether the `@user.venue_manager` value is zero or one.

Comment: yes, but I need a user to have access only to certain venues that I assign to the user. For example I have venues A B & C, and I have a user X. I may need to be able to assign access to user X only for venues A & B

Comment: Then you can use a separate table full of venues that you could then assign a one to many relationship from the users table to the venues table.